# Hows does Significant Location Change work?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, core-location, cllocationmanager

Can anyone confirm how Significant Location Change works?

---

1. movement is calculated when the iPhones cell receiver swaps from one cell tower to another as the user moves around?
2. movement is calculated by triangulating between "visible" cell towers to best calculate the users position?
3. movement is calculated by triangulation between "visible" cell towers based on the settings associated with desiredAccuracy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Number 1 is the right answer. This is the reason, those updates come not very often.

Comment: Perfect, much appreciated. I just wanted to find out how it was working. The docs say it does not use distanceFilter, but they are a little light on what else (if anything) is going on.

Comment: Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: There's no direct reference I know of. I'd assume, `distanceFilter` still applies but I don't think `desiredAccuracy` does.

Comment: @Steven Kramer "It does not rely on the value in the distanceFilter property to generate events." http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. So it's undocumented but in all likelihood Number 1.

Comment: Also, in my observations (as of ios 5, but this may change), the significant change service behaves differently when the device is plugged into a power source than when it is not; if it is plugged in, the location property of a cllocationmanager is always up to date. when it is not plugged in it is not; it will have a timestamp raelative to the last time it determined its location. Also, if the device is plugged in and wifi is available it may use wifi to determine location rather than only cell towers. Lastly, none of these constant updates trigger the cllocationmanager delgate methods.

Answer (score 0):

Don't rely on it working in a specific way. If the way it works isn't documented, you should be open to changes in that respect.