# What Does startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges uses to Deliver Location

Tags: ios, swift, gps, core-location

I want to Know what does startmonitoringsignificantlocationchanges uses to deliver location, is it GPS or Wifi/Internet? My Understanding is it uses cellular or wifi,to know if device has moved significantly but what I don't know is, at time of picking location does it use GPS alone to pick up location.

My Findings are : I travelled 30 KM in City Train but did not get any locations in background and during this journey my Wifi and Cellular data was off. So please tell if Significant fails to provide locations based on GPS only.

Answer (score 1):

Building location apps in the past, I assumed that GPS was only used when startUpdatingLocation() was called. After double-checking the docs, Apple doesn't explicitly state whether significantLocationChanges CAN use GPS, but it is a power-saving option, and their docs specify that it "requires the presence of cellular hardware", which makes me pretty certain that my assumption (and yours) are correct. I'd leave this up for a bit, in case there's a hardware expert who knows for sure. The docs you want: https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager

Answer (score 0):

Like all location functionality, it uses a combination of cell, wifi, and GPS. Use of cell is *primary*. The idea is to keep use of GPS to a minimum, in order to prevent drain on the battery.

You certainly cannot expect this to work with the cell turned off; indeed, if your code properly checks `significantLocationChangeMonitoringAvailable` with the cell off, I would intuitively expect the answer to be `false`.

(Also note that you will not get any events unless you have a location manager with a delegate.)

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this answer "[Hows does Significant Location Change work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885293/hows-does-significant-location-change-work)" (and in WWDC videos from 2013-2015)  Significant location change monitoring uses a technique called [Cell Tower Triangulation](https://www.quora.com/How-does-cell-tower-triangulation-works).

You can think of it as almost the same mechanism as GPS triangulation except that the cellular hardware will be used to gauge distance from nearby cell towers instead of firing the GPS hardware to get signals from actual satellites.

In my experience I've noticed that this method gives accuracy of approx. 1000m. It does not use the GPS hardware and hence is more battery efficient. It is good for coarse location updates. See WWDC 2013 session [Harnessing iOS to Create Magic in Your Apps](http://asciiwwdc.com/2013/sessions/310) where the presenter makes a passing reference to this technology.

Comment: I was under the impression that it uses Cellular triangulation to generate the location change event and power up GPS for like 10 seconds and then give location fetched using GPS. But with this technique I should have received few location updates while testing but I did not receive any. Maybe because cellular data and wifi were off and even though cellular Network and GPS were available, they were not enough to provide location. Is there any explanation for this or is it normal.

Comment: In iOS 9+ you can use (requestLocation)[https://developer.apple.com/reference/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620548-requestlocation] API to get a sigle, high accuracy location fix from the GPS hardware. The location manager will automatically turn off after that. 

There are also a lot of other considerations like updating plist, setAllowsBackgroundUpdates, location authorization, etc.

Also, don't forget to upvote :)